# MongoDB, access record by ID that auto increments after insertion?

Tags: mongodb

I'm new to Mongo and creating a HTTP API that simply adds people documents to a collection, each document has an ID field and this field is incremented as people documents are added.  I also know Mongo records have a `_id` field, but I don't think this solves my problem.

How should I approach this?

So I have a schema:

```
module.exports = mongoose => {
  var schema = mongoose.Schema(
    {
      id: Number,
      name: String,
      role: String,
    },
  );
```

I suspect I could use a pipeline to find the greatest `id` and increment that value in the insertion code.  This would be problematic if `id`s are deleted, then I suspect some other solution would be required.

Comment: In the spirit of keeping things simple: which of your requirements wouldn't be satisfied by using the (required) `_id` field?

Comment: Is `_id` automatically incremented from 0 upon addition of documents to a collection?

Comment: `_id` turns out to be some big number. "id": "64c06fe2697aa332aecb66c1".  I'm looking to use 1, 2, 3, ...

Comment: By default it's an ObjectId not a number. You can manually store whatever (unique) value you want in that field though. Moreover I think it's worth double checking what you're willing to trade in terms of potential code complexity, performance, and maintainability in order to get sequential integers. It's possible to do, but certainly a lot more effort and more error prone to using the built-in capabilities